# How to create a honeypot against ransomware with Windows Powershell?

Tags: powershell, encryption, scripting

Is it possible to create a sort of honeypot against encryptions? As in stepping ahead of mass data loss by a malicious program like cryptolocker and stopping it? How in terms would a script like this look?

I've tried poking around google for and found a couple of discussions. The key is to create a file in a directory typically attacked first (like Recycling bin) and if it is modified by a certain program or user, they are immediately denied access to any further files.

Now I know this is a wide question, but I'm having a hard time gathering useful information and would appreciate straight answers or useful articles. I've even found a way to get around ransomware by using API hooks, though that's a more difficult topic for me.

I will continue researching this on my own, but everything and anything helps.

Thank you.

Comment: That is part of the problem, the moment you publish something with blocking this, the malware authors are going to hook something else invalidating your efforts.  The same problem exists for heuristic based file signature scanning, block file matching X signature..then the malware authors change the file slightly to evade the signature match.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start here https://www.honeynet.org/project and possibly look at monitoring Windows API that deals with encryption, whitelist valid calls and force user confirmation on calls that might be malicious.

Answer (score 0):

To protect network shares:

I've setup honeypot shares on the network which can be monitored to give me an early detection of an infected machine and buy me some time before it reaches something critical.  Name the honeypot shares so that they will be enumerated at the top of the list ('AAAAAAAAA', 'AAAAAAAAB', etc).  Then fill them with 1,000 1MB PDF files.  Give the Everyone group full control to ensure the malware begins there.

Of course, the best protection is to ensure permissions on the share are applied correctly, but this doesn't stop an attack originating from a user account that already has permission there.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There are decryptors available that require unencrypted versions of a file to attempt key recovery. I wonder if you could just put a helpful file in the path of the encryption and keep a copy of the file offline until needed. Then use it to recover the key. Is that too simplistic a view of the problem and solution?